# DateTime format in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, date, datetime, datetime-format, time-format

Can anyone tell please tell me how to change `2018-01-15T08:54:45.000Z` to `2018-01-15 08:54:45` in `PostgreSQL`.

Here my timestamp: `2018-01-15T08:54:45.000Z` is in text format.
I need to split it into two different columns like one for the only date:`2018-01-15` and another is for only time:`08:54:45`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to directly cast your text to a `timestamp` and then cast again to `date` or `time` to get two different columns:

```
SELECT
  ('2018-01-15T08:54:45.000Z'::timestamp)::time AS time,
  ('2018-01-15T08:54:45.000Z'::timestamp)::date AS date
;
```

Comment: Hello @Andrew Whitaker, many thanks for your answer. This code converting the `timestamp` properly but it shows some extra digit after second as example `15:30:59.00163`. In my case its work like `UPDATE table_name SET time = ('timestamp'::TIMESTAMP)::timestamp(0);`